# How to add the value of the table from the script tag to the table of the html where id = #show?

Tags: javascript, html

**How to add the value of the table from the script tag to the table of the html where id = #show?**

```js
var arrHead = new Array();
    arrHead = ['', 'Student Name', 'Department', 'Age']; 

    
    function createTable() {
        var stuTable = document.createElement('table');
        stuTable.setAttribute('id', 'stuTable');  

        var tr = stuTable.insertRow(-1);

        for (var h = 0; h < arrHead.length; h++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th'); 
            th.innerHTML = arrHead[h];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        var div = document.getElementById('cont');
        div.appendChild(stuTable);    
    }

 
    function addRow() {
        var stuTab = document.getElementById('stuTable');

        var rowCnt = stuTab.rows.length;    
        var tr = stuTab.insertRow(rowCnt); 
        tr = stuTab.insertRow(rowCnt);

        for (var c = 0; c < arrHead.length; c++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');          
            td = tr.insertCell(c);

            if (c == 0) {   
                var button = document.createElement('input');

                button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                button.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');

               
                button.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeRow(this)');

                td.appendChild(button);
            }
            else {
                
                var ele = document.createElement('input');
                ele.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                ele.setAttribute('value', '');

                td.appendChild(ele);
            }
        }
    }

    
    function removeRow(oButton) {
        var stuTab = document.getElementById('stuTable');
        stuTab.deleteRow(oButton.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex); 
    }

   
    function submit() {
        var myTab = document.getElementById('stuTable');
        var arrValues = new Array();

        
        for (row = 1; row < myTab.rows.length - 1; row++) {
            
            for (c = 0; c < myTab.rows[row].cells.length; c++) {
                var element = myTab.rows.item(row).cells[c];
                if (element.childNodes[0].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
                    arrValues.push("'" + element.childNodes[0].value + "'");
                }
            }
        }
        var out = document.getElementById('#show');
    document.write(arrValues);
}
```

```css
table { width: 70%; }
        table, th, td { border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse; padding: 2px 3px; text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<body onload="createTable()">
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add New Row" onclick="addRow()" />
    </p>
    <div id="cont"></div>   
    <p><input type="button" id="bt" value="Submit Data" onclick="submit()" /></p>
</body>
<footer>
 
      <table border="4" id="show">
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>dpt</th>
        <th>age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
     </thead>
   </table>
</footer>
```

Comment: Have you tried `var out = document.getElementById('show');`?

Comment: yes but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new row inside the table, loop through the array and create a cell for each item.

Here's the code snippet for the same:

```js
var arrHead = new Array();
arrHead = ['', 'Student Name', 'Department', 'Age'];


function createTable() {
  var stuTable = document.createElement('table');
  stuTable.setAttribute('id', 'stuTable');

  var tr = stuTable.insertRow(-1);

  for (var h = 0; h < arrHead.length; h++) {
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerHTML = arrHead[h];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  var div = document.getElementById('cont');
  div.appendChild(stuTable);
}


function addRow() {
  var stuTab = document.getElementById('stuTable');

  var rowCnt = stuTab.rows.length;
  var tr = stuTab.insertRow(rowCnt);
  tr = stuTab.insertRow(rowCnt);

  for (var c = 0; c < arrHead.length; c++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td = tr.insertCell(c);

    if (c == 0) {
      var button = document.createElement('input');

      button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      button.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');


      button.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeRow(this)');

      td.appendChild(button);
    } else {

      var ele = document.createElement('input');
      ele.setAttribute('type', 'text');
      ele.setAttribute('value', '');

      td.appendChild(ele);
    }
  }
}


function removeRow(oButton) {
  var stuTab = document.getElementById('stuTable');
  stuTab.deleteRow(oButton.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
}


function submit() {
  var myTab = document.getElementById('stuTable');
  var arrValues = new Array();


  for (row = 1; row < myTab.rows.length - 1; row++) {

    for (c = 0; c < myTab.rows[row].cells.length; c++) {
      var element = myTab.rows.item(row).cells[c];
      if (element.childNodes[0].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
        arrValues.push("'" + element.childNodes[0].value + "'");
      }
    }
  }
  var tbodyRef = document.querySelector('#show');
  var newRow = tbodyRef.insertRow();

  // Insert a cell at the end of the row
  arrValues.forEach(item => {
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
    var newText = document.createTextNode(item);
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 70%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="createTable()">
  <p>
    <input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add New Row" onclick="addRow()" />
  </p>
  <div id="cont"></div>
  <p><input type="button" id="bt" value="Submit Data" onclick="submit()" /></p>
</body>
<footer>

  <table border="4" id="show">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>dpt</th>
        <th>age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  </thead>
  </table>
</footer>
```